# Deleting data from SQL Server is not affecting .mdf file size

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in SQL server where the MDF is like 8gb.
Most of it (like 95%) are some logs i keep and i can delete them (or truncate).

Even though i delete the records, the MDF is still the same file. Actually if i use delete it's bigger, if i use Truncate is exactly the same.

What is the correct way to force the database to reflect the new data size?

PS. I've tried to the database to another server and after the move the data from 8GB and deleted logs, it's 350mb. But in the main server even deleted log it still remains 8GB.

Comment: [See also](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95691/97345). The easy way is to shrink your database. The correct way (or rather ways) are more involved, because shrinking is slow and causes horrid index fragmentation. Even if you have to shrink, the important thing is to ensure it won't be necessary again.

Comment: I would like to avoid shrinking database, as i believe it'll get slower. As you mention the important thing - these are log so they will fill again sometime.

Comment: Thus the tradeoff between Space and Speed. It will be slower post shrink but mostly only in allocating new extents as and when required and probably an imperceptible difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reduce the size of the database files, you'll have to shrink it. Shrinking removes empty pages, comparable to defragging a file system or compacting Access databases. This can be done by executing the Shrink command under the Tasks menu of the database in Management Studio or by executing the DBCC SHRINKDATABASE command.

But beware of shrinking databases in production! First get to know what shrinking exactly does, for instance by reading this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-2017

This article is a nice investigation of the impact of shrinking a database and then reorganizing/rebuilding the indexes again. 
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/. Shrinking versus fragmentation, disk space versus performance.